# Is it possible to generate a save file dialog using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

I am posting some data to the server using jquery ajax. The server spews out a file (if the request is successful). I am just wondering how to initiate the save file dialog within the success callback given the results? Thanks.

PS:

The simplest solution is:

```
$('#ExportToExcel').click(function () {
                $('#form').attr({ action: 'bla' });
                $('#form').submit();
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: You mean to ask how to save a local file using javascript (which you can't, as far as I know)? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: the server produces the file depending on the posted data.

Comment: please use a more descriptive title in the future. This will help others looking for the same to find the answer quicker.

Comment: @aron your solution works (can you repost it as you deleted your answer)? Please note, however, that i do not need to save the file first and send the uri back as i stream the data. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It **is** possible to ask the browser to offer the Save File dialog in your situation, yes, with a combination of JavaScript, the server response, and the handling of that response by the browser.

Here's how:

1. Create a form to `POST` the data to the server.
2. Create a hidden `iframe` with a unique name.
3. Set the form's `target` to be the name of the `iframe`.
4. Send the form (e.g., `formElement.submit()`).
5. Have your server respond using the `Content-Disposition` header with the value `attachment`. This is a *suggestion* to the browser that the result should be saved rather than displayed in the browser itself.

If you want to get really fancy, you can use the cookie trick I describe in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064882/what-are-techniques-to-get-around-the-ie-file-download-security-rules/2064957#2064957) so you can get notification when the response is received (whether the server responds with the requested data, or an error). I use that very successfully in a browser-based DHML+JavaScript application where the user can request a custom PDF, and choose to either view it in a browser window (in which case I have the server include the `Content-Disposition: inline` header) or save it as a file (`Content-Disposition: attachment`).

Comment: Can you please let me know how to this: "Set the form's target to be the name of an iframe." Please note I am using the same form for filtering a grid.

Comment: can you please have a look at the my not working iframe solution (see PS of question)? Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkom: You can't do it via `$.ajax` at all, that's what I meant with steps 1-4 above. You literally fill in fields in a form (they can be hidden fields if you like) and use the `submit` method of the form's DOM element to do it. This doesn't tear down your page the way a form submit usually would, because the form has a `target`. You use the cookie trick to know when the response has been received. The user experience is largely the same as your `$.ajax` solution, it's just how you make it happen that's different.

Comment: I am using the same form to filter my grid so I think the 'target solution' would not work. Or should I use a hidden form for the exporttoexcel button (after pressing this button the the user gets the data as excel file depending on the entered form values). I will give it another go tomorrow. Thanks so far.

Comment: @csetzkorn: No reason not to use a form specifically for this purpose. It doesn't even have to pre-exist in the markup, you can create it on-the-fly.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder canyou give me an example for this?

Comment: @bleykFaust: The steps above are all quite straightforward. I suggest giving it a go, and if you run into trouble, post a question showing your code and saying what trouble you've run into.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>**You can't open a save file dialog with pure JavaScript.**</strike>

**EDIT: it seems you can. See [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324784/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-save-file-dialog-using-javascript/5324944#5324944).**

Original answer is still valid:

You could use Flash, or simply redirect to the download page using JavaScript.

For example:

```
$.post('/some/url', function(data) {
    // lets for the moment, assume that you 
    // return a JSON string containing some
    // parameters, data.url being the URL of 
    // your download file
    var downloadUrl = data.url;
    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
});
```

It is not possible to download the file that is being returned directly by your AJAX-request. Instead, save the file on the server - perhaps in a temporary file - and return a URL that downloads the file and removes it from the server afterwards.

Comment: Can I redirect to a URL whilst posting the data in the form? That would be ideal I think. Thanks.

Comment: @Csetz I don't understand what you mean. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Actually, it **is** possible to use JavaScript plus the server response to do what the OP's described.

Comment: @csetzkorn Just return HTTP redirect code, something like 303?