# Download file on the browser

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get the file downloaded at the user browser.
I am using azure-storage SDK. Following is the express code. I can see the files being retrieved on the browser console. But it just is not prompting a download for the user. [image]

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  res.attachment(req.get('blobName'));
  blobService.getBlobToStream(req.get('container'), req.get('blobName'), res, function (error, result, response) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929838/is-content-disposition-attachment-blocked-from-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1):

Request succeeds so problem is not related to express code.

You seem to use `XMLHttpRequest` to send request.

`XMLHttpRequest` gets the file content in response, but it doesn't download the file as an attachment automatically.

We have to add some code to make file downloaded by browser.

```
...
//set type to blob, so that response can be used in createObjectURL method
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response)
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = blobname;
        a.click();
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to using response header so that the browser download the file instead of treating it as the typical response.

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + blobname);
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
```

for further reference you could refer to Mozilla developer's site about [Content-disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: That is already set in the header as you can see from the image attached above