# Iframe onload does not execute after file download?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I show a waiting dialog and then i create an iframe with the url of the file and append it to the document.

```
 Neptune.ShowWaitingDialog();
     iFrame.src = "ExportReportAllMediaDetailsCsv/?" + $.param(object);
     iFrame.style.display = "none";
     iFrame.onload = function () {
        parent.Neptune.CloseWaitingDialog();
    };
    document.body.appendChild(iFrame);
```

If there is an error on the server side the iFrame.onload function executes accordingly and the waiting dialog is closed, however if a file is returned the onload function doesnt get executed and the waiting dialog stays open.

my question is, if a file is returned doesnt the iframe get refreshed and hence cause the onload event to execute? 
if no then is there a way to detect if a file has been returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do that, taken from T.J. Crowder's answer to [this old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064882/what-are-techniques-to-get-around-the-ie-file-download-security-rules), is this:

1. Add a hidden form field or GET parameter called "nonce" (or whatever you want).  Fill it with a unique number or random string, either at page creation time or with JavaScript.
2. On the server, look for the "nonce" parameter and add a cookie called "FILE_READY" (or whatever you want), and set its value to the nonce value.  Return the file as you normally would.
3. On the client, when the form posts or the iframe "src" is set — in other words, when you initiate the file download — start up a JavaScript interval timer to check the current value of the "FILE_READY" cookie. Check like every 100 milliseconds or so; it doesn't have to be super-frequently.
4. As soon as the "FILE_READY" cookie has the value sent in the "nonce" parameter, then you know that the HTTP response has come back from the server.

Works like a charm.