# JavaScript: detect uploading form image finished

Tags: javascript, form-submit

Is there any chance to handle when form submit finished(**ok** or **error**)? I want to upload images or mulitpart data **without javascript libraries**. For example, user clicks `submit` button, after uploading data server responds with `error` or `success` response. Depending on that result I need to do something. Here is example form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload_file">
    <input type="file" name="upload_image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Unless you use AJAX, submitting the form refreshes the page, so you can't detect it.

Comment: If you submit the form, a new page will be loaded. So all your JS stops to exist.

Comment: The above is true only if you don't set `target` on the form to be another window (which can be an iframe).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder You're right. I'm using iframe with target. But I'm stuck with this problem. I need to handle form submit result.

Comment: @bob: That's what my answer describes doing. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I've not access to the server side, I need to solve this problem on the client side. That's why I couldn't use cookies. 
 I did these steps to achieve success (I used jQuery to create/bind element/events. I didn't use AJAX to send form data): 
1. I have **iframe** in my HTML (pay attention, there is no `iframe` in HTML):

```
<form id ="send_message_form" target="multipart_uploader_iframe" 
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload_file">
    <input type="file" name="upload_image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

2. I created `iframe` when submit clicked (I tried to avoid unnecessary `onload` event firing). Notice, after adding `iframe` to body, I added attribute `onload`. Because if I add **onload** attribute while creating iframe, it instantly fired when I append `iframe` to `body`. Now `closePopup` is called once when server responded.

```
$('#send_message_form').submit(function() {
    var customIframe = $('<iframe></iframe>');
    customIframe.attr({
      'id': "multipart_uploader_iframe",
      'name': "multipart_uploader_iframe"
    });

    $('body').append(customIframe);
    customIframe.attr({
      'onload': "closePopup();"
    });
    return true;
});
```

3. When server responds with **responseText** (if it returns with *text/plain* type), **responseText** will be put in `iframe` **body**. Then `iframe`'s **onload** event fires (of course our **closePopup** function). In my case server responded with **OK** or other error text:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript
window.closePopup = function() {
    var error, response, _ref, _ref1;
    setTimeout(function() {
      return $('#multipart_uploader_iframe').remove();
    }, 500);
    try {
      response = (_ref = (_ref1 = frames['multipart_uploader_iframe']) != null ? 
        _ref1.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML : void 0) != null ? _ref : "";
      if (response.indexOf("OK") !== -1) {
        // close here your popup or do something after successful response
        alert('Message has been sent successfully.');
        return $(".popup").dialog('close'); 
      }
    } catch (_error) {
      error = _error;
      throw new Error(error);
    }
    return alert("Error occurred while sending message.");
};
```

I'm really inspired by [this](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/response_data.php) article. I hope this helps someone who has the same problem.

 PS: It worked on IE8

Answer (score 1):

One non-ajax option is to have a hidden `iframe` on the page with a name, and to set the `target` action of your form to the name of that `iframe`. Have the server respond with a cookie that's specific to the form (you might even pass in an `id` the server should use as the cookie name), then on form submit start polling to see if that cookie exists. When the cookie arrives, it means the server has replied to the form post in the `iframe`. You can either put the success/failure information in the cookie itself, or put it in the document that ends up in the `iframe` and have your client-side code scrape it from there. Then take appropriate action.

E.g., in pseudo-code:

```
On The Client                  On The Server
---------------------------    ---------------------------
1. JS assigns ID to form
2. User submits form
3. JS handles submit event,
   starts polling for the
   cookie with the relevant
   ID
                               4. Receives and processes the form
                               5. Responds with success/failure and
                                  cookie
6. JS polling sees cookie,
   reads success/fail from
   cookie or document in
   iframe
7. JS does something appropriate
   with success/fail info
```

I first came up with this technique [to answer this other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064957/157247), immediately used it on a project, and it works a treat. In the case of that question, we were dealing with something that would return a document to download (`Content-Disposition: attachment`) (I used it to show a "Building your document" `div` and then replace that with success/failure when the cookie arrived), but it works perfectly well if you're doing something else.

Comment: How can I know when server responded, you said `When the cookie arrives, it means the server has replied to the form post in the iframe`. Or should I use setInterval?

Comment: @bob: Yes, either `setInterval` or a chained series of `setTimeout`. That's what I mean by "polling."